# Return Nodes and Relations on Query

Tags: neo4j

I have some paths on a Neo4J database.

Here is how my data is arranged

[image: Nodes]

My relationships have a parameter called Distance

I made this query, that returns the origin point and arrival point.

```
MATCH ((po:Ponto)-[r]->(pd:Ponto))
RETURN po AS Ponto, collect(pd) AS Conexoes
ORDER BY po.PontoDeEntrada DESC, po.Identificador
```

The json returned is like this

[image: Return]

I need to return de Distance parameter of Relation into Conexoes object.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Conexoes` can be a collection of maps (where each map has `distance` and `pd` properties):

```
MATCH (po:Ponto)-[r]->(pd:Ponto)
RETURN po AS Ponto, COLLECT({distance: r.Distance, pd: pd}) AS Conexoes
ORDER BY po.PontoDeEntrada DESC, po.Identificador;
```